# How can I type the input/output types of successive transformer functions in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, transform

I have an array of transformer functions where the next one's input type should be the previous one's output type.

The first one's input type and last one's output type can be anything the user specifies.

```
// An array of these:
const transfomFn = (input) => {
  // some transformation details...
  return output:
}
```

How can I properly type these constrains as an array of transformers in TypeScript?

What is the type of this array that can enforce the right input/output types for each transformer in the array?

Thank you.

Comment: Adding some code of the transformers would help ;)

Comment: I have added one example @Raffobaffo

Comment: `(input) => { return output }` is unfortunately not a [mre], since `output` does not exist.  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  If you are asking about an array, give us such an array in the example code.  Ideally you'll provide enough code so that when someone answers the question it will be obvious whether or not it works for you.

Comment: It *might be* that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXjQVm) is what you're looking for, but at what cost?  A chain of functions like this can be collapsed into a single function, so you might as well just do that and apply your constraint at the end.  But without a [mre] I can't be sure if this is what you're talking about.  Please @jcalz mention me if you decide to add a [mre] here.  Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @jcalz , still, this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible in typescript as the array constraints must be statically known.

I would achieve this with a utility class

```js
type Transformer<I, O> = (input: I) => O;

class TransformerChain<
  I,
  O
> {
  private transformers: ((x: unknown) => unknown)[] = [];
  public addTransformer<U>(
    transformer: Transformer<O, U>
  ): TransformerChain<I, U> {
    const newTransformer = new TransformerChain<I, U>();
    newTransformer.transformers = [...this.transformers, transformer as any];
    return newTransformer;
  }
  public transform(data: I): O {
    let cur: any = data;
    for (const t of this.transformers) {
      cur = t(cur);
    }
    return cur as O;
  }
}

const t1 = new TransformerChain<number, string>();
const t2 = t1.addTransformer((x) => x.toString());
const t3 = t2.addTransformer((s) => [s] as const);
const result = t3.transform(3); // "result" is type readonly [string]
```

Comment: Dear, each transformer has different input/output types. But they need to satisfy the constraint mentioned in the question. Plz, read it again.

Comment: @geeko see relevant edit